# Li-Ion battery charging process with a microcontroller

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

I was planing to charge a 4S battery pack with onboard-protection with a microcontroller since I need to vary the threshold voltages of charge/discharge. With lots of cheap microcontrollers on my desk, some googling on charging process and reading some datasheets, I was wondering if the charging could be done with some ADC pins on a microcontroller. I think these steps are considered while charging a battery cell. The question is about the **procedure in general**, not just my use case.

1. When the battery is empty, it gonna take a lot of current going through it which gonna degrade it or make it hot and eventually kaboom. **So, Always check the current going through cells and keep it down using a PWM switch.**
2. **Don't let the battery voltage go higher than the defined threshold or 4.1v;** this is easy since a regulated, external supply voltage is provided with the voltage level exactly regulated equal to the desired cell voltages.
3. **Watch the temperature.** Don't let it get hot and vary the input current till it's in the safe temperature range, or shut it off completely before things get nasty.

These steps simply need just a few pins on a microcontroller and an external switch and current sense. Is the process mentioned above safe, at least in low charging currents (like C/10)? And am I missing a few tips or steps?

Comment: You forgot 4: If a cell goes above or below the voltage of other cells by an x amount (let's say 50mV) charge or discharge it until it is near or equal to other cells.
 5. If any cell goes below 2.7V, disconnect the whole pack.
You should also check the current consumption of the MCU; it shouldn't significantly shorten the life of the battery.

Comment: No, it's not safe. Lithium batteries need a two stage constant current - constant voltage charge cycle which should be terminated when complete. This sounds like an accident waiting to happen. There are dedicated ICs that handle this properly.